# Unable to Get Second Window to Populate Widgets

Tags: tkinter, widget, root

I've worked on, and feel like I did a decent job, on redoing my amino acid study guide code, but now I have an issue where the second window will show up, but doesn't show any widgets. There's no error code when I run the program, so I'm a bit lost on what I should do. I've tried looking at alternatives, but nothing has worked thus far. Any help would be appreciated. I'm also still very much a beginner, so constructive criticism is better than deconstructive criticism.

I'm going to include a portion of the code, but not all of it as it's still a couple hundred lines of code.

```
class QuestionWindow(object):

        #######################################################

    #This will open up the question window and allow the user to study
    def openQuestionWindow(self):
        
        self.QuestionWindow = Toplevel(root)
        self.QuestionWindow.title('Second Window')

        self.IDCall = 0
        self.pKCall = 0

    def aminoSelect():

        AminoAcidList = [

        ["Alanine", "Ala", "A", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Arginine", "Arg", "R", 2.2, 9.8, 12.48],
        ["Asparagine", "Asn", "N", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Aspartic Acid", "Asp", "D", 2.2, 9.8, 3.71],
        ["Cysteine", "Cys", "C", 2.2, 9.8, 8.33],
        ["Glutamine", "Gln", "Q", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Glutamic Acid", "Glu", "E", 2.2, 9.8, 4.15],
        ["Glycine", "Gly", "G", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Histidine", "His", "H", 2.2, 9.8, 6.00],
        ["Isoleucine", "Ile", "I", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Leucine", "Leu", "L", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Lysine", "Lys", "K", 2.2, 9.8, 10.53],
        ["Methionine", "Met", "M", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", "F", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Proline", "Pro", "P", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Serine", "Ser", "S", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Threonine", "Thr", "T", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Tryptophan", "Trp", "W", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Tyrosine", "Tyr", "Y", 2.2, 9.8, 10.07],
        ["Valine", "Val", "V", 2.2, 9.8]

        ]
        AminoAcid = random.choice(AminoAcidList)

        return AminoAcid

        self.AcidName = aminoSelect()

        self.AminoAcidPic = Image.open(f"{self.AcidName[0]}.png")

        self.AminoAcidPicResize = self.AminoAcidPic.resize((200, 200))

        self.ActualImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.AminoAcidPicResize)

        self.ImageLbl = Label(self.QuestionWindow, image = self.ActualImage).pack()

        self.ImageLbl.config(image = self.ActualImage)
        
        self.ErrorMsgLbl = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = ' ').pack()


        if (MainWindow.SelName_V.get() == 1) & (MainWindow.SelPk_V.get() == 1):
            self.IDCall += 1
            self.pKCall += 1
            CombinedWindow()
            
        elif (SelName_V.get() == 1) & (SelPk_V.get() == 0):
            self.IDCall +=1
            AminoAcidID()

        elif (SelName_V.get() == 0) & (SelPk_V.get() == 1):
            self.pKCall += 1
            pKaQuestion()


        self.CheckAnswerBtn = Button(self.QuestionWindow, text = "Check Answers", command = CheckAnswer).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5,side = RIGHT)

        self.NewAminoBtn = Button(self.QuestionWindow, text = "Change Amino", command = AminoChoice).pack(pady = 5, padx = 5,  side = RIGHT)

        self.CloseBtn = Button(self.QuestionWindow, text = "Close", command = lambda: QuestionWindow.destroy()).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = LEFT)

        self.ShowAnswerBtn = Button (self.QuestionWindow, text = "Show Answers", command = RevealAnswer) .pack(pady = 5, padx = 5, side = LEFT)
        self.ShowAnswerBtn.config(state = DISABLED)

        self.QuestionWindow.mainloop()
```

```
    #######################################################

    #This will ask for ID if ID questions are selected
    def AminoAcidID():
        
        self.NameQuest = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = "What is the full name of the amino acid?",     wraplength = 300).pack()
        self.NameAnswer = Entry(self.QuestionWindow, width = 20, bg = "yellow").pack()
        self.NameReveal = Label (self.QuestionWindow, text = " ", width = 20).pack()

        self.Let3Quest = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = "What is the three letter code of the amino acid?", wraplength = 300).pack()
        self.Let3Answer = Entry(self.QuestionWindow, width = 20, bg = "yellow").pack()
        self.Let3Reveal = Label (self.QuestionWindow, text = " ", width = 20).pack()

        self.Let1Quest = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = "What is the one letter code of the amino acid?", wraplength = 300).pack()
        self.Let1Answer = Entry(self.QuestionWindow, width = 20, bg = "yellow").pack()
        self.Let1Reveal = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = " ", width = 20).pack()


    #######################################################
```

```
    #######################################################

#This will act as the main, interactable window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Biochemistry Start Window")
root.geometry('400x200')

QWindow = QuestionWindow()

Introlbl = Label(root, text = "Welcome to the amino acid study aid. Down below you can choose what you'd like to focus on.", wraplength = 300).pack()

SelName_V = IntVar()
SelPk_V = IntVar()

def SwitchState():

    if SelName_V.get() == 0 and SelPk_V.get() == 0:
        QuestionOpenbtn.config(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        QuestionOpenbtn.config(state = NORMAL)

SelName = Checkbutton(root, text = "Amino Acid Identification", command = SwitchState, wraplength = 100, variable = SelName_V, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).pack()
SelPk = Checkbutton(root, text = "Amino Charge", command = SwitchState, height = 2, width = 10, variable = SelPk_V, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).pack()

QuestionOpenbtn = Button(root, text = "Show Selection Questions", command = QWindow.openQuestionWindow)
QuestionOpenbtn.pack()

CloseWindowBtn = Button(root, text = "Close", command = lambda: root.destroy())
CloseWindowBtn.pack()

QuestionOpenbtn.config(state = DISABLED)

root.mainloop()
```

My original attempt involved global variables, but I'm trying to stay away from that. I've also tried using different classes, but I couldn't get the primary window class to interact with the second.

Answer (score 0):

Without you full code it's difficult to know what other errors there might be, but based on the code you provided there are  a few.

1. your instance methods need to have `self` passed as their first argument.
2. You need to invoke the functions that build the widgets or they will never run which gives you an empty window with no content.
3. Once you return from a function or method, all of the remaining code in the function will never be run.
4. The return value from `.pack` method is None.  So if need to keep a reference to a widget, then you need to call `.pack` on a sepearte line.
5. In the code you posted there is no MainWindow defined so that throws an error.

Also see inline notes in example below:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class QuestionWindow(object):

    def openQuestionWindow(self):
        self.QuestionWindow = Toplevel(root)
        self.QuestionWindow.title('Second Window')
        self.IDCall = 0
        self.pKCall = 0
        self.aminoSelect()  # <- needs to be called to build the widgets on second window.


    #  using `.pack` must be done on different line if you want to keep a ref
    # to the widget
    def AminoAcidID(self):
        self.NameQuest = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = "What is the full name of the amino acid?",     wraplength = 300)
        self.NameQuest.pack()
        self.NameAnswer = Entry(self.QuestionWindow, width = 20, bg = "yellow")
        self.NameAnswer.pack()
        self.NameReveal = Label (self.QuestionWindow, text = " ", width = 20)
        self.NameReveal.pack()
        self.Let3Quest = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = "What is the three letter code of the amino acid?", wraplength = 300).pack()
        self.Let3Answer = Entry(self.QuestionWindow, width = 20, bg = "yellow")
        self.Let3Quest.pack()
        self.Let3Reveal = Label (self.QuestionWindow, text = " ", width = 20)
        self.Let3Reveal.pack()
        self.Let1Quest = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = "What is the one letter code of the amino acid?", wraplength = 300)
        self.Let1Quest.pack()
        self.Let1Answer = Entry(self.QuestionWindow, width = 20, bg = "yellow")
        self.Let1Answer.pack()
        self.Let1Reveal = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = " ", width = 20)
        self.Let1Reveal.pack()

    def aminoSelect(self):  #  < -- needs self as first arg

        AminoAcidList = [

        ["Alanine", "Ala", "A", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Arginine", "Arg", "R", 2.2, 9.8, 12.48],
        ["Asparagine", "Asn", "N", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Aspartic Acid", "Asp", "D", 2.2, 9.8, 3.71],
        ["Cysteine", "Cys", "C", 2.2, 9.8, 8.33],
        ["Glutamine", "Gln", "Q", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Glutamic Acid", "Glu", "E", 2.2, 9.8, 4.15],
        ["Glycine", "Gly", "G", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Histidine", "His", "H", 2.2, 9.8, 6.00],
        ["Isoleucine", "Ile", "I", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Leucine", "Leu", "L", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Lysine", "Lys", "K", 2.2, 9.8, 10.53],
        ["Methionine", "Met", "M", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", "F", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Proline", "Pro", "P", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Serine", "Ser", "S", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Threonine", "Thr", "T", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Tryptophan", "Trp", "W", 2.2, 9.8],
        ["Tyrosine", "Tyr", "Y", 2.2, 9.8, 10.07],
        ["Valine", "Val", "V", 2.2, 9.8]

        ]
        self.AcidName = random.choice(AminoAcidList)
        self.AminoAcidPic = Image.open(f"...")

        self.AminoAcidPicResize = self.AminoAcidPic.resize((200, 200))

        self.ActualImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.AminoAcidPicResize)
        self.ImageLbl = Label(self.QuestionWindow, image = self.ActualImage)
        self.ImageLbl.pack()
        self.ImageLbl.config(image = self.ActualImage)

        self.ErrorMsgLbl = Label(self.QuestionWindow, text = ' ')
        self.ErrorMsgLbl.pack()


        if (SelName_V.get() == 1) and (SelPk_V.get() == 1):
            self.IDCall += 1
            self.pKCall += 1
            CombinedWindow()

        elif (SelName_V.get() == 1) and (SelPk_V.get() == 0):
            self.IDCall +=1
            self.AminoAcidID()

        elif (SelName_V.get() == 0) and (SelPk_V.get() == 1):
            self.pKCall += 1
            pKaQuestion()


        self.CheckAnswerBtn = Button(self.QuestionWindow, text = "Check Answers", command = CheckAnswer)
        self.CheckAnswerBtn.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5,side = RIGHT)

        self.NewAminoBtn = Button(self.QuestionWindow, text = "Change Amino", command = AminoChoice)
        self.NewAminoBtn.pack(pady = 5, padx = 5,  side = RIGHT)

        self.CloseBtn = Button(self.QuestionWindow, text = "Close", command = lambda: QuestionWindow.destroy())
        self.CloseBtn.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5, side = LEFT)

        self.ShowAnswerBtn = Button (self.QuestionWindow, text = "Show Answers", command = RevealAnswer)
        self.ShowAnswerBtn.pack(pady = 5, padx = 5, side = LEFT)
        self.ShowAnswerBtn.config(state = DISABLED)

        self.QuestionWindow.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Biochemistry Start Window")
root.geometry('400x200')

QWindow = QuestionWindow()

Introlbl = Label(root, text = "Welcome to the amino acid study aid. Down below you can choose what you'd like to focus on.", wraplength = 300)
Introlbl.pack()

SelName_V = IntVar()
SelPk_V = IntVar()

def SwitchState():

    if SelName_V.get() == 0 and SelPk_V.get() == 0:
        QuestionOpenbtn.config(state = DISABLED)
    else:
        QuestionOpenbtn.config(state = NORMAL)

SelName = Checkbutton(root, text = "Amino Acid Identification", command = SwitchState, wraplength = 100, variable = SelName_V, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).pack()
SelPk = Checkbutton(root, text = "Amino Charge", command = SwitchState, height = 2, width = 10, variable = SelPk_V, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).pack()

QuestionOpenbtn = Button(root, text = "Show Selection Questions", command = QWindow.openQuestionWindow)
QuestionOpenbtn.pack()

CloseWindowBtn = Button(root, text = "Close", command = lambda: root.destroy())
CloseWindowBtn.pack()

QuestionOpenbtn.config(state = DISABLED)

root.mainloop()
```